# How do I grep non-zero words in a file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

I want to grep all strings that are not `0` in a file. Is there a way to do that?

The file looks something like the following:

```
0
0
0
0.12
0
0
```

and I would like the output to be:

```
0.12
```

Comment: an example with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with `awk` do:

```
awk '$1' file
```

This will skip all lines with `0` in it.

If you like print all words without `0` then try this:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i!~/0/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
```

Comment: Weird it was accepted, since the current solution does not match the required output, because `0.12` does contain a `0`. You can maybe say `awk '$1' file`.

Comment: @fedorqui There was no data example, just remove lines with  `0`